# How to make `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` ignore modifier keys and how to print the key to a string in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, keypress, keydown, keyup

In VB, I usually put my code for when keys are pressed in the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` subs. However, I would prefer it if this code could be put in the `Timer_Tick`.

So I implemented the method shown below in the code where the program creates a `List (Of Keys)` upon starting, and then the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` subs adds or removes the `Keys` from the `List`.

To debug, the program draws a string of all of the `Keys` in the `Paint` sub which is refreshed every frame.

This method of handling key presses works fine mostly, except for the following problems I've encountered:

1. `keysPressed(i).ToString` doesn't draw `,` or any non-letter characters as I would expect it to. Instead, it draws `Oemcomma`. Is there a way to fix this? (I know it's not important for now as it's just a debugging feature, but I would still like to know how to get around this for the future)
2. The modifier keys are a nuisance for me. After being pressed, the `KeyUp` sub isn't called once released (I suspect this is because they modify themselves) and some keys aren't detected at all (like `fn`).

   In addition, if I were to press and hold `A`, then press `Shift` and then release `A`, then `KeyUp` for `A` isn't called (as it has been modified) which means that `Keys.A` is not removed from my list. I would like `KeyUp` for `A` to be called whether or not `A` has been modified.

   Is there a way to tell VB to ignore all modifier keys in the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` subs? (here I mean ignore as in ignore all modifications, despite still being able to detect the modifier key being pressed)
3. When I press a load of buttons (over 10), then it seems that they are not all detected at once (only 6 or so appear in the list). Is there a way to avoid this bug, or is this a limitation of using VB?

   In fact, occasionally, when I press a few more buttons whilst holding another one, the one I was holding seems to be 'cancelled out' by being removed from the list until I release. (There are quite a few bugs which appear when I press a lot of keys).
4. When I press multiple keys down at the same time, what exactly happens? Is `KeyDown` called multiple times for each key, or is it actually possible for a `KeyDown` to represent multiple keys? In which case, what exactly would happen in my program?

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim keysPressed As New List(Of Keys)

    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

        If Not keysPressed.Contains(e.KeyData) Then keysPressed.Add(e.KeyData)

        If e.KeyData = Keys.Escape Then End
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp

        keysPressed.Remove(e.KeyData)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles screenTimer.Tick
        Refresh()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

        For i = 0 To keysPressed.Count - 1
            e.Graphics.DrawString(keysPressed(i).ToString, New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black, 10 * i, 540)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You got into trouble by using KeyDown, that provides the *virtual* key code.  The same anywhere in the world.  You can't ignore KeyPress, the event that fires when a typing key is pressed.  Not the same anywhere in the world, it produces the glyph according to the user's keyboard layout and the state of the modifier keys.  Like Keys.A => 'A' or 'a' or nothing on an English keyboard layout but Keys.A => 'Q' or 'q' or nothing on a French keyboard.  Gets lots more convoluted on keyboard layouts with an AltGr key.  Or a Chinese keyboard, etc.  Don't try to hard to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, code it yourself. It's great the way it is for your purposes functionality-wise, and debugging wise, I prefer it that way, so maybe you should take my advice and not fight it. Consider looking at a trace of all the keystrokes and seeing , mixed in with a bunch of otherwise sensible seeming key names. Imagine Ctrl+, and etc. (when making this code you really need to debug or console trace every event)
2. So rip apart the keydata by taking out the modifiers. There isn't a way to change the way the keydatas come to you. It's inconvenient for some purposes, but useful for some others.
3. It's your keyboard's fault. In general you can't press many keys at once. It has nothing to do with VB or .net
4. Precisely what you expect happens; one keydown can only represent one key. If you can even find a way to store information about more than one key inside the KeyEventArgs, then you're a magician

Despite not using winforms events, the code here does what you're attempting: https://github.com/TASVideos/BizHawk/tree/master/BizHawk.Client.EmuHawk/Input ; It receives key events in bunches, but processing them is more or less the same as if they came from winforms. But believe it or not, we actually have to go to effort to reconstruct the way winforms delivers them with the modifiers combined with the keystrokes (see point #2)--not because of compatibility with old winforms code, but because that's the way we *prefer* it.

Comment: Thank you. For point 1., surely there is a way around this? Whenever I type text (whether it's in a textbook in VB, a search bar, or Microsoft Word), the correct text appears. Surely there is a way to access how the system interprets keypresses? I mean - even the textbox control in VB prints a comma as `,` which is the way I want it.

Comment: No. Applications interpret logical keystrokes. Applications are commonly translating this themselves. Windows does have a way to receive a ',' instead of an OemComma--its called WM_CHAR and should be on the KeyChar event in .net, but I promise you, you won't like it.

Comment: But I don't understand. Surely there's a method which translates the `Key` to its system representation. That's what the VB does when it receives input for a textbox. Although the way things are is ok for debugging, I would still like to change it as this application may become part of a game. In the game, I would allow the player to change which set of keys they would like for their input. In this case, I would need to convert the `Keys` to their string representation. As an example of a few games which do this: Bubble Tanks and Boxhead.

Comment: THERE ISN'T. The `Key` you're receiving IS it's system representation. You're wanting a method which translates a `Key` to some kind of sensible ascii character. That's WM_CHAR and you won't like the way that interacts with your attempts to get more detailed control from KeyUp and KeyDown